# Cabal install HaskellForMaths fails

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I'm trying to install Quipper using this [readme](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/quipper/README). Cabal-install fails on installing Lattices:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring HaskellForMaths-0.4.8...
Building HaskellForMaths-0.4.8...
Preprocessing library HaskellForMaths-0.4.8...
[ 1 of 58] Compiling Math.QuantumAlgebra.TensorCategory ( Math/QuantumAlgebra/TensorCategory.hs, dist/build/Math/QuantumAlgebra/TensorCategory.o )
[ 2 of 58] Compiling Math.NumberTheory.Prime ( Math/NumberTheory/Prime.hs, dist/build/Math/NumberTheory/Prime.o )
[ 3 of 58] Compiling Math.Algebras.VectorSpace ( Math/Algebras/VectorSpace.hs, dist/build/Math/Algebras/VectorSpace.o )

Math/Algebras/VectorSpace.hs:9:26:
    Module `Prelude' does not export `(<*)'

Math/Algebras/VectorSpace.hs:9:32:
    Module `Prelude' does not export `(*>)'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
HaskellForMaths-0.4.8 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
Lattices-0.0.2 depends on HaskellForMaths-0.4.8 which failed to install.
```

I tried to install HaskellForMaths, but it fails with same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're trying to build HaskellForMaths with a version of the base package that does not export `*>` and `<*`, these were probably added in base version 4.8.0.0 which shipped with GHC 7.10.1.

I would suggest that you upgrade to the latest GHC (7.10.2).